# Add additional right-click taksbar functionality to Outlook

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there any way of adding additional contextual items to the menu get when you right click Outlook 2010 in the taskbar on Windows 7?

Currently I have the 5 tasks that are there by default (New Email Message, etc.) but I would like to add my quick steps to here.

Ideally I am after a setting with Outlook or Windows, or a registry change here rather than a third party program.

Answer (score 1):

The open-source project [Jumplist Extender](http://code.google.com/p/jumplist-extender/) may be of use to you.

Jumplist Extender's features include:

> **Add your own Program Tasks**
>
> You can add any action you want on your jumplist, provided it has a
>   keyboard shortcut to your program. Make easy-to-access jumplist items
>   for your everyday tasks! (Works with command line switches, too!)
>
> **Pin Any Type of File**
>
> Add ANY file and ANY folder to your jumplist -- and even rename them
>   on the list! Windows only allows you to add files assigned to (or
>   "openable by") the program -- Extender bypasses that limitation.
>
> **Create Extensions to your Programs**
>
> Use AutoHotKey scripting to extend and add functionality to your
>   programs, easily accessible from your own jumplist! Add a "Save to
>   Desktop Notes" function to Notepad, or add "Snip and upload to
>   ImageShack" to Snipping Tool!
>
> **Share your Jumplists with Others**
>
> Export and import your jumplists into "Jumplist Packs"! Upload your
>   Jumplist Pack to the web, and enable others to download and enjoy your
>   work!

I hope this application meets your needs.

Comment: It's close to what I was after, but I was hoping for a registry fix or setting within Outlook rather than having a program running in the background to control it. Sorry, I should have been more specific in the question.